# Prolog Program To Check If A Number Is Prime

Tags: prolog, primes

I wrote the following program based on the logic that a prime number is only divisible by 1 and itself. So I just go through the process of dividing it to all numbers that are greater than one and less than itself, but I seem to have a problem since I get all entered numbers as true. Here's my code...

```
divisible(X,Y) :-
    Y < X,
    X mod Y is 0,
    Y1 is Y+1,
    divisible(X,Y1).

isprime(X) :-
    integer(X),
    X > 1,
    \+ divisible(X,2).
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @WillNess I'm really glad that there are people like you who would take from their time to review the question, the answers and understand them and contribute. It's really something that I hope I can do. Kudos for you guys

Comment: @WillNess I think all of my time on stackoverflow was receiving help and not helping others and that makes me sad.

Comment: you're most welcome (though I personally didn't do much here); I'm sure you'll pay it forward whenever it's possible for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm a beginner in Prolog but managed to fix your problem.

```
divisible(X,Y) :- 0 is X mod Y, !.

divisible(X,Y) :- X > Y+1, divisible(X, Y+1).

isPrime(2) :- true,!.
isPrime(X) :- X < 2,!,false.
isPrime(X) :- not(divisible(X, 2)).
```

The main issue was the statement `X mod Y is 0`. Predicate `is` has two (left and right) arguments, but the left argument has to be a constant or a variable that is already unified at the moment that the predicate is executing. I just swapped these values. The rest of the code is for checking number 2 (which is prime) and number less than 2 (that are not primes)

I forgot to mention that the comparison `Y < X` is buggy, because you want to test for all numbers between 2 and X-1, that comparison includes X.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is a follow-up to [@lefunction's previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31302174/4609915).

`isPrime2/1` is as close as possible to `isPrime1/1` with a few changes (highlighted below):

```
isPrime2(2) :-
    !.
isPrime2(3) :-
    !.
isPrime2(X) :-
    X > 3,
    X mod 2 =\= 0,
    isPrime2_(X, 3).

isPrime2_(X, N) :-
    (  N*N > X
    -> true
    ;  X mod N =\= 0,
       M is N + 2,
       isPrime2_(X, M)
    ).
```

Let's query!

```
?- time(isPrime1(99999989)).
% 24,999,999 inferences, 3.900 CPU in 3.948 seconds (99% CPU, 6410011 Lips)
true.

?- time(isPrime2(99999989)).
% 5,003 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (89% CPU, 6447165 Lips)
true.
```

Comment: @lefunction. How about parallelizing to multi-cores?

Comment: on my machine the time doesn't register.

Comment: @lefunction. In the sense of Gustavson's law: Pick a bigger problem size.

Comment: @j4nbur53. Now, I have doubts, too. ;) I guess it would be best to get rid of FP-sqrt and do calculate squares of integers. Will edit my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @j4nbur53. Done. Better now?

Answer (score 3):

`X mod Y is 0` always fails, because no expressions allowed on the left of `is`.

Change to `0 is X mod Y`, or, better, to `X mod Y =:= 0`

Answer (score 2):

[agarwaen's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23282600/4609915) does not perform well on large numbers.  This is because it is not tail recursive (I think).  Also, you can speed everything up with a few facts about prime numbers.

1) 2 is the only even prime number

2) Any number greater than half the original does not divide evenly

```
isPrime1(2) :-
    !.
isPrime1(3) :-
    !.
isPrime1(X) :-
    X > 3,
    (  0 is X mod 2 
    -> false
    ;  Half is X/2,
       isPrime1_(X,3,Half)
    ).

isPrime1_(X,N,Half) :-
    (  N > Half 
    -> true
    ;  0 is X mod N
    -> false
    ;  M is N + 2,
       isPrime1_(X,M,Half)
    ).
```

`1 ?- time(isPrime1(999983)).
% 1,249,983 inferences, 0.031 CPU in 0.039 seconds (80% CPU, 39999456 Lips)
true.`

**EDIT1**

Is it possible to take it a step further?  `isPrime_/3` is more efficient than [`isPrime2/1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282097/prolog-program-to-check-if-a-number-is-prime/31306584#31306584) because it compares only to previously known primes.  However, the problem is generating this list.

```
allPrimes(Max,Y) :- 
    allPrimes(3,Max,[2],Y).

allPrimes(X,Max,L,Y) :-
    Z is X+2,
    N_max is ceiling(sqrt(X)),
    (  X >= Max 
    -> Y = L;
    (  isPrime_(X,L,N_max)
    -> append(L,[X],K),       %major bottleneck
       allPrimes(Z,Max,K,Y)
    ;  allPrimes(Z,Max,L,Y)
    )).

isPrime_(_,[],_).

isPrime_(X,[P|Ps],N_max) :-
    (  P > N_max  
    -> true     %could append here but still slow
    ;  0 =\= X mod P,
       isPrime_(X,Ps,N_max)
    ).
```

Answer (score 2):

I thing that is elegant way:

```
isPrime(A):-not((A1 is A-1,between(2,A1,N), 0 is mod(A,N))),not(A is 1).
```

1 IS NOT PRIME NUMBER, but if you don't think so just delete **not(A is 1)**.

Answer (score 1):

Was trying something else. A pseudo primality test based on [Fermats little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem):

```
test(P) :- 2^P mod P =:= 2.

test2(P) :- modpow(2,P,P,2).

modpow(B, 1, _, R) :- !, R = B.
modpow(B, E, M, R) :- E mod 2 =:= 1, !,
   F is E//2,
   modpow(B, F, M, H),
   R is (H^2*B) mod M.
modpow(B, E, M, R) :- F is E//2,
   modpow(B, F, M, H),
   R is (H^2) mod M.
```

Without the predicate `modpow/4` things get too slow or integer overflow:

```
?- time(test(99999989)).
% 3 inferences, 0.016 CPU in 0.016 seconds (100% CPU, 192 Lips)
true.

?- time(test2(99999989)).
% 107 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
true.

?- time(test(99999999999900000001)).
% 4 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (81% CPU, 190476 Lips)
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded

?- time(test2(99999999999900000001)).
% 267 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (87% CPU, 1219178 Lips)
true.
```

Not yet sure how to extend it to a full primality test.

Answer (score 0):

Using `findall` and `between`

```
is_prime(N) :- 
             HalfRange is round(N/2),
             % Iterate over all X values in [2, HalfRange] and if (N mod X) is 0 then put X in ModList list
             findall(X, (between(2, HalfRange, X), 0 is mod(N, X), !), ModList),
             % N is prime iff ModList is empty
             length(ModList, ModCount), ModCount =:= 0.
```

Comment: This is not "fail fast". Very inefficient.

Comment: @brebs Adding `,!` would make it fail fast, Now `ModCount` would be either 0 (prime) or 1 (not prime).

Comment: `forall` would be more elegant than `findall`, to fail fast without needing a cut.