# Prolog , Need to find out composite number from a list and sum

Tags: prolog

I am new in prolog, when user input list of number it will only sum the composite number.
composite Number: `4,6,8 ... etc`. So far I done sum of list in `prolog`.But really got problem how I can find composite number in prolog?

Can find sum by this

```
list_sum( []          , 0        ) .
list_sum( [Head|Tail] , TotalSum ) :-
  list_sum(Tail,Sum1) ,
  Total = Head+Sum1 .
```

Comment: You just need to make a predicate which tells you if a number is composite and then use it as a condition in your `list_sum` predicate.

Comment: That might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23282600/562769

Comment: Thanks, i am really confused how i can do that , i mean how i can define in prolog composite condition ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a predicate `is_composite/1` that succeed if its argument is a composite number. This is how I'd do it :

```
sum_of_composite_numbers( Ns , S ) :-
  sum_of_composite_numbers( Ns , 0 , S )
  .

sum_of_composite_numbers( [] , R , R ) .
sum_of_composite_numbers( [N|Ns] , T , R ) :-
  ( is_composite(N) -> T1 = T+N ; T1 = T ) ,
  sum_of_composite_numbers( Ns , T1 , R )
  .
```

A composite number is:

> a positive integer that has at least one positive divisor other than one or the number
>   itself. In other words, a composite number is any positive integer greater than one that
>   is not a prime number [[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number)].

And a prime number, of course, is its converse,

> a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself.
>   A natural number greater than 1 that is not a prime number is called a composite number.
>   [Wikipedia]

So one way of defining a composite number would be to check for primeness, something like:

```
is_composite(N) :- N > 1 , \+ is_prime(N) .
```

There's lots out there on how to determine primeness. You should be able to figure it out.

Comment: @user3601675, you have to enter it. Nicholas shows the definition in his answer (read toward the bottom of the answer).