# Basic primality test predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog, primality-test

I am trying to create a predicate `isPrime/1` that checks if a given number is prime or not. I have come up with the following code:

```
primeRec(_, 2).
primeRec(X, Y) :- Y > 2, X mod Y-1 > 0, primeRec(X, Y-1).

isPrime(2).
isPrime(X) :- X > 1, X mod 2 > 0, primeRec(X, X).
```

but it does not seem to work, and I have no idea why. I've found my code to follow the same idea as [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301678/primality-test-predicate-isprime-1-in-prolog), except that mine always returns `false.` for any `?- isPrime(X).` with X bigger than 2, which obviously should not happen.

Comment: "I have no idea why" - can debug the program using e.g. `trace` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to define another variable, say `Y1`, and unify it with the evaluation of `Y-1`, i.e., `Y1 is Y - 1` and use `Y1` instead of `Y-1` in the second rule for `primeRec/1.` This because if you want to evaluate an arithmetic expression you need to use `is`.

```
primeRec(X, Y) :- Y > 2, Y1 is Y - 1, X mod Y1 > 0, primeRec(X, Y1).
```